# Get user spent time on android app

Tags: android

I have a scenario that I want to get my user's time spent on my android app. I want to send that time to server associated with user name. In my app, I have login functionality so that user's other information can be saved in sharedpreference to use for sending to server. I also want to send time spent on that app to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can start timer based on your activities that are on foreground and measure the time.This should not be difficult.